# Flutter http post data when click the button

Tags: flutter, http

I want to send post data "1" or "2" int value when the button is pressed with flutter (http package). How can I do that?

My home page screen like this;

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
 
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                var url = Uri.parse(
                    'http://test.com/control.php');
                var response = await http.post(url, body: {'status': 2});
                print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
                print('Response body: ${response.body}');
              },
              child: Text('Open'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                var url = Uri.parse(
                    'http://test.com/control.php');
                var response = await http.post(url, body: {'status': 2});
                print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
                print('Response body: ${response.body}');
              },
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Sorry for my english and Thank you for your helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
final body = jsonEncode({'status': 1});

final url = Uri.http('http://test.com', 'control.php');

final response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: body
    );
```